# How to select balance in Excel across multiple Exact Online divisions as with budgets across multiple accounts?

Tags: invantive-control, exact-online

I'm using Invantive Control for Excel to create a Exact Online report using formulas.

I use the following formula to get the Period Balance:

```
=IF(I_EOL_BAL_PDE($F$1;$F$2;I$2;$E11;;)
```

I would like to get results for a certain set (or all) of my divisions and not just the one active in Exact Online.

I was under the impression that all divisions would be selected when the cell would be left empty, such as in:

```
I_EOL_BGT_PDE_LINE
```

for budgets across multiple General Ledger Accounts. But this doesn't seem to be the case. When the first Excel parameter to `I_EOL_BDE` is unspecified, it seems to use the default division (the one I worked with last in Exact Online).

How should I use the formula to get results from all the divisions I like to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `i_eol_bal_pde` you can select divisions as follows:

- Leave value out: the default division is used taken from Exact
- 232323: use division 232323
- @be: use the default division of Exact with alias be (normally Belgium)
- 232323@be: use division 232323 of Exact with alias be (Belgium)

There is currently no option to select multiple divisions as with for instance General Ledger accounts. You can use:

```
I_EOL_BAL_PDE(xxx) + I_EOL_BAL_PDE(yyy) + I_EOL_BAL_PDE(zzz)
```